# Use parameters to create or merge relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I often add large amounts relationships between existing nodes and I'm wondering if parameters could increase performance. So far I do this by building individual Cypher strings and submitting them in Cypher transactions (using py2neo 1.6.4).

The queries look like:

```
MATCH (a:Label1 {name: 'value'}), (b:Label2 {name: 'value'})
MERGE (a)-[r:RELATES {name: 'foo', value: 'bar'}]->(b)
RETURN r
```

Would parameters increase performance? How can I use parameters with this query?

I tried using `FOREACH` around the whole query and pass parameters, but `MATCH` is not allowed inside `FOREACH`. I don't see if/how I can parameterize both the `MATCH` and the `CREATE`/`MERGE`.

An alternative would be to use `MERGE` only, but this will create new nodes if a part of the query doesn't match.

---

**Update**

I think the answer is that I can't parameterize the complete query. But as the Wes Freeman suggests performance increases if I use parameters for the `MERGE`, even if the query contains only one set of parameters for one relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in an array and do something like this:

```
MATCH (a:Label1 {name: {name1}}), (b:Label2 {name: {name2}})
FOREACH (rel in {rels}|
  MERGE (a)-[r:RELATES { name: rel.name, value: rel.value }]->(b)
)
```

Of course, it's hard to pull out the `r` values afterward.

Params:

```
{
 "name1":"value",
 "name2":"value",
 "rels":[{"name":"foo","value":"bar"}, ...]
}
```

Comment: This would help if I add many relationships between the same nodes. Unfortunately, each relationship is between two different nodes (data from a N x M matrix). So I would still need one query per relationship :)

Comment: In that case, just use the transactional API one rel at a time.

Comment: You should pass parameters for the values though.

Comment: Transactional API is what I am doing right now. Parameters for values are faster even if the number of relations doesn't change?

Comment: Especially if the number of relations doesn't change. It will cache the statement.